# mprun magic command gets ERROR: Could not find file /tmp/ipykernel_75919/1494889556.py

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, memory-profiling

I need to do a memory use profiling of a function. I'm using a jupyter notebook in with Python 3.8.10, and I've insalled succesfully the memory_profiler 0.60 with no errors. When I load the memory_profiler, using `%load_ext memory_profiler`, no error appears, but when I try to use mprun (`%mprun -f  suma2 suma2(0.2,0.2)`), then this error appears:

```
ERROR: Could not find file /tmp/ipykernel_75919/1494889556.py
```

Here you have a screenshot of the whole code:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe profiling functions defined within a jupyter notebook with `%mprun` is still not supported. You will have to define your function in a separate python file and import it to your jupyter notebook to memory profile it.

E.g. in your instance, you would create a file `funcy.py`:

```
def suma2(a,b):
    return a+b
```

and then import it in the notebook:

```
from funcy import suma2
```

which you then can follow up with the memory profiler code.